# PHP Bootstrap multi select options

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I am using `PHP` which populates the bootstrap multi `selectpicker`  from `MySQL` database but the problem is it only selects the last option instead of multiple options, I don't know what I am missing in it? Here is my my code

```
function MultiBindCombo($tablenames, $columnnames1, $columnnames2, $comboname, $selectedopt) {
    global $conn; 
    $sql="SELECT ". $columnnames1. ", " . $columnnames2 . " FROM ". $tablenames;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if( ! $result ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    echo '<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" name="' . $comboname . '" multiple="multiple">';
    $array = explode(',', $selectedopt);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            foreach ($array as $select_option){
            if($row[$columnnames1] == $select_option) {
                $print_selected = 'selected';
            } else {
                $print_selected = '';
            }
            echo $select_option;
            }
        echo '<option data-tokens="' . $row[$columnnames1] . '" value="' . $row[$columnnames1] . '"' .$print_selected. '>' . $row[$columnnames2] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: As I said it only selects the last option instead of all selected values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all selected values in a multiselect you need to use `name` attribute with `[]`:

```
echo '<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" name="' . $comboname . '[]" multiple="multiple">';
```

After that you can iterate over `$_POST[$comboname]` with a `foreach`.

**Update**:

Let's look closer to your code here:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach ($array as $select_option){

        // You iterate over every value of array, so in the end
        // `$print_selected` is defined depending on value of the 
        // last `$select_option`

        if($row[$columnnames1] == $select_option) {
            $print_selected = 'selected';
        } else {
            $print_selected = '';
        }

        // remove this. Why you echo `$select_option`?
        echo $select_option;
    }
    echo '<option data-tokens="' . $row[$columnnames1] . '" value="' . $row[$columnnames1] . '"' .$print_selected. '>' . $row[$columnnames2] . '</option>';
}
```

Rewrite it as:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $print_selected = ''; 
    foreach ($array as $select_option){
        if($row[$columnnames1] == $select_option) {
            $print_selected = 'selected';

            // break `foreach` as you found the right item
            break;
        }
    }
    // if right item is not found - `$print_selected` is empty

    echo '<option data-tokens="' . $row[$columnnames1] . '" value="' . $row[$columnnames1] . '"' .$print_selected. '>' . $row[$columnnames2] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: I already set a select box name with `[]` thats not a problem it prints the multiple values I echo `$selectedopt` but it only select the one option instead of multiple

Comment: works perfectly thanks can you please tell me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't break the loop. So `$print_selected` value was __always__ defined based on the last element of `$array`.

Comment: Ohhh my mistake thanks for clarification and helping me out from this